# How can I intercept the string from a complex string

Tags: .net-core

I use asp.net core mvc, I need to intercept string when receive it from the bakend because I want to show the expected string(B0ERO49J67SFK) to the view.

```
Indoland--Detachable/B0ERO49J67SFK/ref=_arp_d_rvw_fmt?ie=UTF8&formatType=current_format
```

How to write a regular expression to intercept this string.

var regex = //[0-9][A-Z]{13}/g;

The above regex is I wittend, but it gets the null, can not intercept the correct string.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the incorrect regex, about jquery regex, you can try this example.

```
var str="Husband-Pillow-Detachable-Removable-Adjustable/B0ERO49J67SFK/ref=cm_cr_arp_d_rvw_fmt?ie=UTF8&formatType=current_format";
var result=/(?<=\/)[0-9A-Z]{13}(?=\/)/.exec(str);
console.log(result);
```